# Check if string will convert to date in PHP

Tags: php, validation, date

An easy follow up From an earlier question ( [Date functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670970/date-functions-in-php) ) I have the following code:

```
$date_str = "Jan 14th 2011";
$date = new DateTime($date_str);
echo $date->format('d-m-y');
```

What I am wondering is if there is an easy way to check if $date_str will convert to a date so that I can stop prevent the error when it fails?

Basically I am looking to avoid using try catch statements but perhaps that is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid try/catch?

Comment: Good question @Juhana it is because I was hoping to make an error handler that logged all problems with the code and this is not really an error so much as it is wrong input that needs to be sent back to the user for re-entry.

Comment: @JJJ many times you just want to use nice object-like formatting/date handling and don't really care if the date is not there - try/catch is overkill in that case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), the DateTime constructor will throw an exception if the date can't be parsed properly. So...

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime($date_str);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("It puked!");
}
```

If you're using the procedural interface, you'll get a boolean false instead, so...

```
$date = date_create_from_format(...);
if ($date === FALSE) {
    die("It puked!");
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the constructor logic will accept anything that loosely resembles a date or time zone expression (absolute or relative) in plain English so you'll find that [stuff like `today`, `last monday -4 seconds`... `a` *are* valid dates](http://3v4l.org/F8p9A).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that's awesome, not sad :)

Comment: @jave.web Trust me. A program that happily produces invalid output and forces you to perform tedious manual checks every time is neither reliable nor time saving.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that's something totally different and what you are complaining about is lack of date type limiting - which I agree could be there - however the fact it also knows how to process fluent language out of the box is a handy thing :) lack of validation/limiting? yes Not handy? No.

Answer (score 1):

Since DateTime class will throw an exception if incorrect values are passed. and the only way you should be dealing with exceptions is by using try catch statement.

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime($date_str);
    $date->format('d-m-y');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //$e will contain the caught exception if any.
}
```

i see no reason for skipping try catch method. if you want to validate the date input then you might want to have a look at php's [checkdate](http://in.php.net/checkdate) function

Comment: Thannks @Ibrahim. Hey I just looked at your website and it is not working at the moment.

Comment: very difficult, I prefer `strtotime()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216564/best-method-to-input-and-validate-custom-datetime-in-php-form